# What is the name for this template programming technique, and is this standard C++?

Tags: c++, templates

My boss who has written this code calls it a default template parameter, but I'm not sure it's the name. This looks somewhat like partial specialization, but with more intuitive syntax. Is it even standard C++?

```
template<class T, bool auto_delete=true> class ArrayPtr : public  Array<T*> {
public:
    ArrayPtr(){}
    ~ArrayPtr(){Done();}

    bool    Done() { 
                if (auto_delete){
                    FOR(i, Array<T*>::GetSize()) delete (*this);
                }
                return Array<T*>::Done();}
} ;
```

Comment: Template or not, I see *derivation*.

Comment: `auto_delete` has a default template argument of `true`, and derives from `Array<T*>`. In any case, the code seems baaaad. Especially the `FOR` macro. Wtf. Also, repeatedly `delete`ing `*this`? Whaaat?

Comment: This looks like the broken code technique to me. Does it even compile? (`*this` is not a pointer, so you cannot `delete` it)

Comment: @Xeo: I no, rite? He has his own special style :) But you're dodging the topic.

Comment: That looks like boss code indeed..

Comment: @Violet: But you might want to recommend him [a good book](http://tinyurl.com/so-cxxbooks). This code is broken beyond hell, and should be burninated.

Comment: Your boss has a very special taste in code formatting too.

Comment: See [temp.param]/9, i.e. 14.1/9

Comment: @VioletGiraffe _Special_, indeed. Terrible, also. Abysmal, even.

Comment: By the way, don't forget to throw him a link to this question some time soon. `;)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other issues aside, the use of `bool auto_delete=true` is standard C++.

Officially, this is known as a *default template-argument*. From C++11 **14.1 Template parameters**:

> 9 A *default template-argument* is a *template-argument* (14.3) speciﬁed after `=` in a *template-parameter*. A *default template-argument* may be speciﬁed for any kind of *template-parameter* (type, non-type, template) that
>   is not a template parameter pack (14.5.3).

Answer (score 1):

The code is standard C++; it is sometimes useful to declare a default template argument. For example, if you define a class `Vector3D<T>` (in the sense of a mathematical 3D vector) it may make sense to default `T` to `double`. As for the Standard Library `std::vector` template, it is declared as follows:

```
template < class T, class Alloc = allocator<T> > class vector;
```

Notice how the allocator used by the class defaults to the specific allocator provided by a traits class; most of us normally specify only the `class T` and let the default allocator handle the underlying data structure. Most other templates in the C++ Standard Library are similarly defined with some default parameters.

That brings me to the specific case you illustrate. Other style issues aside, the purpose seems to be suitable for type traits: the type `T` could have an associated `auto_delete_trait` declared as follows:

[Live Code Example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/1eZZ21%240)

```
#include<iostream>

template<typename T>
struct auto_delete_trait {
  static const bool value = true;
};

template<typename T>
struct myclass {
  void method(T val) {
    std::cout<<"value: "<<val<<std::endl;
    if(auto_delete_trait<T>::value) {
      std::cout<<"auto_delete enabled"<<std::endl;
    } else {
      std::cout<<"auto_delete disabled"<<std::endl;
    }
  }
};

// suppose that ints are not supposed to be auto-deleted (obviously
// this is an example; the concept of "auto-delete" does not make
// sense here)
template<> 
struct auto_delete_trait<int> {
  static const bool value = false;  
};

int main() {
  myclass<double> c1;
  myclass<int> c2;
  c1.method(1.234);
  c2.method(1);

  // expected output:
  // value: 1.234
  // auto_delete enabled
  // value: 1
  // auto_delete disabled

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I like how you have "if you define a class Vector it may make sense to default T to double", but don't mention that `std::vector` has a default template argument :D